# Regular expression for class with whitespaces using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I found that method BeautifulSoup.find() splits class attribute by whitespaces.
In that case I couldn't use regular expression as show in code below.
Could you somebody help me to get right way find all 'tree children' elements:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

r_html = "<div class='root'>" \
       "<div class='tree children1'>text children 1 </div>" \
       "<div class='tree children2'>text children 2 </div>" \
       "<div class='tree children3'>text children 3 </div>" \
   "</div>"

bs_tab = BeautifulSoup(r_html, "html.parser")
workspace_box_visible = bs_tab.findAll('div', {'class':'tree children1'})
print workspace_box_visible # result: [<div class="tree children1">textchildren 1 </div>]
workspace_box_visible = bs_tab.findAll('div', {'class':re.compile('^tree children\d')})
print workspace_box_visible # result: [] >>>> empty array because 
                                         #class name was splited by whitespace character<<<<

# >>>>>> print all element classes <<<<<<<
def print_class(class_):
    print class_
    return False

workspace_box_visible = bs_tab.find('div', {'class': print_class})

# expected: 
# root
# tree children1
# tree children2
# tree children3

# actual:
# root
# tree
# children1
# tree
# children2
# tree
# children3
```

Thanks in advance,

***==== comments ==========***

stackoverflow site don't allow add comments more than 500 characters, 
so I added comments here:

Above, it was example to show how to BeautifulSoup looking for required classes.

But, If I have DOM structure like:

```
 r_html = "<div class='root'>" \
       "<div class='tree children'>zero</div>" \
       "<div class='tree children first'>first</div>" \
       "<div class='tree children second'>second</div>" \
       "<div class='tree children third'>third</div>" \
   "</div>"
```

and when need to select controls with class attributes: '***tree children***' and '***tree children first***', 
All of the methods described in your(Padraic Cunningham) post aren't work.

I found a solution with using regex:

```
controls = bs_tab.findAll('div')
for control in controls:
    if re.search("^tree children|^tree children first", " ".join(control.attrs['class']  if control.attrs.has_key('class') else "")):
    print control
```

and another solution:

```
bs_tab.findAll('div', class_='tree children') + bs_tab.findAll('div', class_='tree children first')
```

I know, it's not good solution. and I hope that BeautifulSoup module has appropriate method for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different ways depending on the structure of the html, they are css classes so you could just use `class_=..` or a css selector using *.select*:

```
In [3]: bs_tab.find_all('div', class_="tree")
Out[3]: 
[<div class="tree children1">text children 1 </div>,
 <div class="tree children2">text children 2 </div>,
 <div class="tree children3">text children 3 </div>]

In [4]: bs_tab.select("div.tree")
Out[4]: 
[<div class="tree children1">text children 1 </div>,
 <div class="tree children2">text children 2 </div>,
 <div class="tree children3">text children 3 </div>]
```

But if you had another *tree* class elsewhere that would find then also.

You could use a selector to find divs that contains *children* in the class:

```
In [5]: bs_tab.select("div[class*=children]") 
Out[5]: 
[<div class="tree children1">text children 1 </div>,
 <div class="tree children2">text children 2 </div>,
 <div class="tree children3">text children 3 </div>]
```

But again if there were other tag classes with children in the name they would also be picked up.

You could be a bit more specific with a regex and look for *children* followed by one or more digits:

```
In [6]: bs_tab.find_all('div', class_=re.compile("children\d+"))
Out[6]: 
[<div class="tree children1">text children 1 </div>,
 <div class="tree children2">text children 2 </div>,
 <div class="tree children3">text children 3 </div>]
```

Or find all the *div.tree's* and see if the last names in *tag["class"]* *starstwith* *children*.

```
In [7]: [t for t in bs_tab.select("div.tree") if t["class"][-1].startswith("children")]
Out[7]: 
[<div class="tree children1">text children 1 </div>,
 <div class="tree children2">text children 2 </div>,
 <div class="tree children3">text children 3 </div>]
```

Or look for children and see if the first css class name is equal to *tree*

```
In [8]: [t for t in bs_tab.select("div[class*=children]") if t["class"][0] == "tree"]
Out[8]: 
[<div class="tree children1">text children 1 </div>,
 <div class="tree children2">text children 2 </div>,
<div class="tree children3">text children 3 </div>]
```

Comment: I answered for your comments in first post.
Thanks,