# How can I search for a specific string that varies by a single character in beautiful soup python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to search for all variations of a string that is completely the same other than a single character. Here is an example of the string:

AccordionPanelTab cond1_left
AccordionPanelTab cond2_left
AccordionPanelTab cond3_left

I would normally just iterate through a for loop however this string is the class I'm trying to use in beautiful soup. My code looks like this

```
sessionSwell = dryscrape.Session()
sessionSwell.visit(swellURL)
responseSwell = sessionSwell.body()
soupSwell = BeautifulSoup(responseSwell, "lxml")

swellDayData = soupSwell.findAll("div", {"class": "AccordionPanelTab cond1_left"})
```

I was thinking there is a command that I could put in the string in the place of the 1 that would tell the computer I do not care what is in this place. I'm sure this is a simple fix but I researched far and wide and couldn't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: You want something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824121/regular-expression-for-class-with-whitestaces-using-beautifulsoup/38825064#38825064., it may be as simple as `class_="AccordionPanelTab"` depending on how the html looks which you have not provided so only you can know for sure

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding, you needed a list of all the strings that needs to match your conditions.You can use regular expression for that.

[re.findall(pattern, string)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list of matching strings.

You can do that by